# Find if coordinates form a complete path

Tags: matlab, image-processing, graph

So I have a list of points that generally form a sort of circular shape except there are often little offshoots from the circle that are essentially just lines from say the border of the circle going in a certain direction. I want to create a function that when given this list of coordinates/points finds whether there exists a complete path in this set of points.

I've thought about creating a start point and finding whether there exists a path that doesn't repeat points (ie (1,1) -> (2, 1) -> (1,1) disallowed) and could get back to the start point; however, if the start point is in an offshoot of the circle, this wouldn't work.

For instance, a list of coordinates

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 3], [3, 4], [4, 4], [3, 2], [3, 1], [3, 0], [2, -1], [1, -1], [0, -1]]
```

would form a complete path while if I take out `[1, -1]` it would not form a complete path.

Comment: You don't have to get back to the starting point to detect a cycle. You only need to get back to a previously-visited point that is not the current point's immediate predecessor.

Comment: @beaker That is true, however, there could a small clump of points that would trigger this false detection. In the example I gave, it would work, however, I am working with large amounts of data which does not guarantee that there would be no cases like what I mentioned.

Comment: Is this path maybe a skeleton? Given your answer, it looks like a standard end-point pruning would do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I went with is to turn the list of neighbors into a matrix, turn that matrix into a matrix of logicals, and then assuming you know for sure a point within the loop, use imfill function on that point and check if the [1,1] coordinate had been converted.

```
    mat = zeros(length, length);
    mat(coordinates) = 1;
    mat = logical(mat);
    mat = imfill(mat, [length/2 length/2]);
    if mat(1) == 1
       not closed loop
    else
       closed loop
    end
```

Several assumptions with this code are that the middle point lies within the loop and not already filled and the (1,1) coordinate value will not already be filled which are assumptions I can make with the data I am working with.